# How to store API URLs in a files like app.config/web.config for a React app hosted in AWS S3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3, environment-variables

WHAT IS THE PROBLEM?

I have a React app hosted in AWS S3. The app makes a request to an API URL and displays the result. The API URL changes based on the environment.

DEV environment - https://192.168.0.1/api/users

TEST environment - https://192.168.0.2/api/users

I want to have these different API URLs in a file like app.config/web.config so that I can change the URL anytime I wanted (thus avoiding building/deploying).

WHAT HAVE I TRIED?

1. I tried adding these URLs in .env file as follows:

DEV_API_URL = https://192.168.0.1/api/users

TEST_API_URL = https://192.168.0.2/api/users

After this, I am able to consume these URLs from the React code as follows:

env.DEV_API_URL

env.TEST_API_URL

However, if I want to have these URLs changed, I should edit the .env file, build and deploy using Jenkins on every change.

2. The other method I tried was, to have these URLs as environment variables in Jenkins. In this method also, I need to build and deploy on every change

WHAT I NEED?

Could you let me know a place (like app.config/web.config) where I can change these URLS and my React app pick it up immediately without build/deploy?

Comment: I just redeploy whenever i need a change like this. but you can have another api endpoint to get the config such as https://my-web-site.com/credentials/staging. that will return {url: 192.168.0.1}. but i wont complicate the app like this.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the URL in a database, and fetch the URL each time you need to reference the value in React.

It adds a lot of DB overhead, but it won't require any deployment. You just change the url in the DB as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you might want to use environment variables. Basically, you can build something for development / staging / production and have files named `.env.development` `.env.production` where you can have environment variables, like: `REACT_APP_API_URL=https://example.com` and use it in your code with `process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL`. Please note that they should be prefixed with `REACT_APP`.
Some libraries that you might use are: [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv), [env-cmd](https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd)

Comment: I want to change the URL after deploy. When I change the URL, I should not edit any file in repo/commit/build/deploy. The app. should pick the URL value as a .NET app does from app.config/web.config file.